# get value of the input being clicked. It is in an array of multiple inputs in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I hope you can help me with this. I need to acces the value of the input being clicked in javascript. What I have is an array of multiple products that are mapped into the html. I can acces each product id by putting `e.target.id` but I can't do the same with the input.

```
//Every button has its own button so I select them all and do a foreach. 

let prodClick = document.querySelectorAll(".clickedButton");
prodClick.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", ajax);
});
//Then I create an ajax function where I am going to control the "state" of every element
function ajax(e) {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = "/create-order";

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("divToInsert").insertAdjacentHTML `
              <h1> This is the ID of the product you selected: ${e.target.id} </h1>
            `
    }
  };
  request.open("GET", url);
  request.send();
}
```

I explained a little of the code in comments.
Here is my html. Multiple divs like this one are created with the attributes of each product. Each one has an input named quantity. If I do a `getElementsByName` I get an array of all the inputs. (Every product comes from the database, so It it not possible to just select them with an ID, because it will eventually change)

```
foreach article in products
     p= articule.name
     p= article.brand
     p= article.stock
     p= article.price
     input(type="number" name="quantity" class="w-3/12") 
     button.buttonClicked(type='button' id= article.id) Add
```

How can I get which input is being clicked? **I just need the value of quantity of each product**. When a product button is clicked, It appends to an array of objects which has an id, and a quantity property.

[image: This are my elements]

Comment: `e.target` should be the actual node, in this case. I don't see any HTML. By the way, in XHR2 you can change `request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {` to `request.onload = function(){` and get rid of that `}` at the end of your status test. Note that you could use `this` in the correct context *(think arrow function)* instead of `e.target`, as well.

Comment: Can you put it as a comment so I can understand a little better please?  I don't quite understand, how that is going to help me get the value of the input, in the box where the button I'm clicking is.

Comment: If `e.target` is the node, the value of an input would be `e.target.value`. Looks like an improper use of a Template literal.

Comment: If I do `e.target.value` it returns `<empty-string>` Because I am listening to the button and the `e` is the event from it. I am passing an `ID` to my button that's why I am able to get it by doing `e.target.id`. Anyways thanks for commenting and trying to help

Comment: Yeah, you would have to have a reference to the input. That would reference `item` at each step of your loop *(that's your button)*. If there is a button for every input, show your HTML.

Comment: If the input is in the same DIV as the button, use `e.target.closest("div").querySelector(".w-3/12").value` to get the input.